# python: print fasttext query to file

Tags: python, fasttext

I'm rather new to this
I'm trying to perform a nearest neighbors fasttext query and get the readout printed to a file.

My code:

```
model=fasttext.load_model("dir/cc.en.300.bin")

list = ("past", "present", "time")
for i in list:
    print(i)
    model.get_nearest_neighbors(i)
```

returns the elememnts of the list but does not return the nearest neighbors.
Ideally I´d also have each query result printed to its own file eventually -but need to get the query working first.
Thanks to anyone willing to help!

Answer (score 0):

That is what `get_nearest_neighbors` is supposed to do. It gives you [a list of the nearest neighbors](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/blob/2d453cdd3646b69667edaebd723191f5b0ad3574/docs/unsupervised-tutorials.md) (by default it gives you the 10 nearest)

I think if you pass in `get_nearest_neighbors(i, k=1)`, that will let you get just the single nearest.

Comment: but it does not. Thats the problem. ^^ Within the for loop `get_nearest_neighbors` does not return anything.

Comment: are you printing the result? `print (get_nearest_neighbors(i, k=1))` ?

Comment: ah, that explains. Thanks.

Comment: Last (hopefully) question on this: `with open('dir/output.txt', 'w') as f:
    for i in list:
        f.write(model.get_nearest_neighbors(i))
        f.write('\n')
f.close()
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-14-28f9534c5b3c>", line 3, in <module>
    f.write(model.get_nearest_neighbors(i))

TypeError: write() argument must be str, not list` --> my question is, how do I print the list to a file?

Comment: Depending on your needs.
If you only want print the list to a file, you can convert the list to a string, using `str`: `f.write(str(model.get_nearest_neighbors(i)))`.

So, if the list is `lst=['test','try']`, `str(lst)="['test', 'try']"`.
But maybe it's not the best option to store this type of data.